# What limitations are there when I try to run an Adobe Creative Cloud application as a RemoteApp?

Tags: remote-desktop, adobe-creative-cloud, remoteapp

I posted this as a question on [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1330651/), but after waiting a while, there have been no replies and low views.

I'm planning on installing [Adobe Creative Cloud] applications on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, then running them on my other computers (including Windows RT) using [RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx). I tried doing that, but I saw something weird: Whenever I try running the Creative Cloud app as a RemoteApp, it keeps launching it on the server desktop rather than on the remote device. Other applications, like Adobe Bridge, do not have that issue and launch properly on the remote machine. I have two questions:

- Is the behavior above a bug or is it intended behavior?
- Other than that, are there any problems I will encounter when I try to run Adobe applications as RemoteApps? For example, will Premiere Pro previews render properly on the remote machine?

If you answer this question, could you also post it as a reply on Adobe Forums?

Comment: Wouldn't there be a licensing issue here? If you're licensed to do this, that is to run as many copy as you want for as many computers as you want, then you would be paying a lot of money. If you're paying a lot of money, than Adobe should provide support directly. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @MarkLopez I did talk to an Adobe rep about accessing them over RDP, and they said that I can.

Comment: I hate to ask because it seems condescending, but have you ensured the remoteapp is configured properly to be used as a remoteapp? Are there any system logs that provide an error or explanation of behavior?

Comment: @Raystafarian I am not RemoteApp-ing the "standard" way. I am instead using a Registry workaround to disable the allow list. This is because when I installed the Remote Desktop Services role, it gave me an error that said that I must be logged on as a domain user to configure RD Services. I then installed the Active Directory role, but in order to create a new domain, I must create a forest, and to create a forest, I must own a Web domain, which I don't. (http://gparyani.com is not actually mine)